# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am writing a program which encrypts a text file with two keywords. My code below is not finished, but there is an error when encrypting.

My code:

```
while True:
    print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt your textfile?')
    option = input().lower()
    if option in ["e","encrypt","d","decrypt"]:
        break
    else:
        print('Enter again')


key1 = input("Enter your first keyword ").upper()
if len(key1) == 0:
      print ('Your keyword has to be more than one character. Enter again')

key1 = ([ord(k) for k in key1])
key1 = (key1)*100
print (key1)

key2 = input("Enter your second keyword ").upper()
if len(key2) == 0:
    print ('Your keyword has to be more than one character. Enter again')

key2 = ([ord(e) for e in key2])
key2 = (key2)*100
print (key2)

efile = input('Enter the text file you want to change (with .txt)')
efile = open(efile).read()
efile = efile.upper()

k = 0
e = 0

string = ''
for symbol in efile:
    ctext = ord(symbol)
    if ctext == 32:
        ctext = chr(ctext)
        ctext = str(ctext)
        string += ctext
#print(string)

else:
    while len(string)> 0:
        ctext += key1[k]
        if ctext > 90:
            ctext -= 64
        ctext += key2[e]
        if ctext > 90:
            ctext -= 64
        ctext = chr(ctext)
        ctext = str(ctext)
        string += ctext
        k+=1
        e+=1
print(ctext)


   ctext += key1[k]
```

Python throws the following error when running my code:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me advice in solving this as I have no clue! :)

Comment: "there is an error" What error? What is the input? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Coding a crypto script is a good way to learn both some math and Python. But just a reminder here. NEVER use home rolled crypto code in production!

Comment: At what line does the error happen?  For your print statements (debugging with print is fine) print not just the variable , but also it's type.My guess is line `if ctext > 90:` where you are comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: You `ctext` variable alternates between being a number and a string. While Python allows this, this is probably not a very good idea. At some point, `ctext` is a number but you treat it as a string, or vice versa.

Comment: Don't just edit the post with trash when it is closed. This doesn't help others that may have a similar issue. All context of answers is lost without the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `ctext` equals to 32, you are converting it to a `string`, when the `for` loop is exhausted, the `else` scope is being executed in which you are trying to run:

```
ctext += key1[k]  # ctext is a string, key1[k] is an int
```

Same as:

```
# Python 3
variable = '2'  
variable += 1
>> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: I don't want all of ctext to equal 32, I meant if it is 32(space in ASCII), do not encrypt it. How do I make ctext into an array of integers?